# find the treasure.

Tags: puzzle

Guys I just started college ( engineering) so if this question was easy just help me out please.
There are three boxes,and three messages:

Message 1 / box 1: the treasure is not in the box 1.

Message 2 /box 2: the treasure is not in the box 2.

Message 3/ box 3: the treasure is in the box 2.

Use the tables of truth to find the box that has the treasure.

So what I did is this:
I supposed that the treasure is in box 1 and then I found this in the table of truth;
Message 1: false
Message 2: true
Message 3: false
I did the same thing with box 2 and 3 but I found two " true" and one " false"
And since there must be two "false" and only one " true" then the treasure is box 1.

Comment: What have you already done? What do you know about truth tables? Adding these details will encourage people to help you as it won't appear you are merely looking for an answer :)

Comment: Given the information you provided, the treasure could be in any of the boxes, or in none, or in all. Do you know anything about how many of the messages are true? What are the assumptions that are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you make more assumptions about the truth value of the messages, say 'one message is false' you can't draw a logical conclusion.

If, for example only one message is false then as you said message 2 and 3 are contradictory and so if message 2 is false, the treasure is in box 3, if message 3 is false, the treasure is in box 2. Here you see that the assumption 'one message is false' still doesn't provide enough information to draw a conclusion. For that you'd need a more specific assumption like 'message 1 and 2 are right'.

Just given the messages with no information and let all be true gives a contradiction and the treasure could be everywhere. Or nowhere.